# Angularjs input form array post as array of json objects

Tags: angularjs

in html, i wanna create a input form which gives me this result on post, on sign up, i want to post user address as array of addresses have objects like 
"gender" : "MALE",
    "addresses" : [{
        "street" : "123 street",
        "post_code" : "45663"
    }]

Html i wrote like

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.addresses[].street" >
<input type="text" ng-model="user.addresses[].post_code" >.
```

Comment: Actually i don't wanna populate, i want the array of object when i'll post the form.

Comment: Thanks guys, i've solved this. Here is the answer.
https://jsfiddle.net/junaidcs/b9p50yjt/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {

    gender: "MALE",
    addresses: [

      {
        street: "123 street",
        post_code: "45687"
      }

    ]

  }
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl" class="container">
    <label>Gender</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.gender" class="form-control">
    <br/>
    <div ng-repeat="address in user.addresses">
      <label>Street</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="address.street" class="form-control">
      <br/>
      <label>Postcode</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="address.post_code" class="form-control">
      <br/>
    </div>
    <pre>{{user | json}}</pre>


  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually i don't wanna populate, i want the array of object as request  when i'll post the form

Comment: Thanks, @sylwester, i've solved this like http://jsfiddle.net/junaidcs/b9p50yjt/3/